# Selenium and BeautifulSoup scraper only scrapes first page of results

Tags: python, loops, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have built a scraper, which works just fine in terms of handling data, but for some reason, it only scrapes the first page of the desired search.

I have two functions, one to find the elements I want in the page and the other to search for a NEXT link and click it if it exists. Otherwise, the scraper prints just that page and continues. I am using the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

letters = ["x"]
for letter in letters:
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        #driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

        driver.get("http://sam.gov")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button[title='Search Records']").click()

    except:
        print("Failed for " + letter)
        pass
    else:



        driver.find_element_by_id('q').send_keys(letter)
        driver.find_element_by_id('RegSearchButton').click()

        def findRecords():
            bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
            tableList = bsObj.find_all("table", {"class":"width100 menu_header_top_emr"}) 
            tdList = bsObj.find_all("td", {"class":"menu_header width100"})

            for table,td in zip(tableList,tdList):
                    a = table.find_all("span", {"class":"results_body_text"})
                    b = td.find_all("span", {"class":"results_body_text"})
                    hf = open("sam.csv",'a')
                    hf.write(', '.join(tag.get_text().strip() for tag in a+b) +'\n')
        def crawl():
            if driver.find_element_by_id('anch_16'):
                print("Found next button")
                findRecords()
                driver.find_element_by_id('anch_16').click()
                print("Going to next page")
            else:
                print("Scraping last page for " + letter)
                findRecords()

            print("Done scraping letter " + letter + "\nNow cleaning results file...")

            seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
            for line in fileinput.FileInput('sam.csv', inplace=1):
                    if line in seen: continue # skip duplicate

                    seen.add(line)
                    print(line)
            print("Scraping and cleaning done for " + letter)

        crawl() 
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `try` statement? What kind of error is thrown?

Comment: I was using the `try` `except` when I was using PhantomJS as my webdriver, it was failing to discover the search button in some iterations. But I don't have a problem with that part when i use Chrome driver so it doesn't throw any error either way. 

The scraper is not throwing any sort of error. It's going to completion, but it is only completing the first page and exits gracefully. I was think it might be something to do with my `if` loops instead of `while`, but that was just remaining true. Or it could be something with the functions.

Comment: I cannot see any of the id's you are searching for on the page.